# How to access signals in submodules with multiple modules?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, test-bench

I have the following Verilog file named `main.v`:

```
module m1(input a, b, output wire c);

assign c = a & b;

endmodule

module main(input x, y, output wire z);

wire k;
m1 m1_inst(.a(x), .b(y), .c(k));
assign z = x ^ k;

endmodule
```

After that, I have a test bench named `tb_main.v` which has an instantiation as shown below:

```
`include "main.v"
reg a, b;
wire b;
main main_dut(a, b, c);

$display("%b", main_dut.m1.a);
$display("%b", main_dut.main.y);
$display("%b", m1.a);
```

When I simulate that testbench, I get the error `unresolved reference to m1` and `unresolved reference to main`.

How do I solve this problem? I do not want to separate modules in the `main.v` file into different files.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using some module names instead of module **instance** names in your hierarchical specifiers.

For example, in `main_dut.m1.a`:

- `main_dut` is a module instance name
- `m1` is the name of the module, not the instance

You must only use module instance names.  This is a complete code example that compiles without errors ([also on EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/mySC)):

```
module m1 (input a, b, output wire c);
    assign c = a & b;
endmodule

module main (input x, y, output wire z);
    wire k;
    m1 m1_inst (.a(x), .b(y), .c(k));
    assign z = x ^ k;
endmodule

module tb_main;
    reg a, b;
    main main_dut (a, b, c);
    initial $display("%b", main_dut.m1_inst.a);
    initial $display("%b", main_dut.y);
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to maintain explicit connectivity. So instead of

```
reg a, b;
wire b;
main main_dut(a, b, c);
```

, do something like

```
reg a, b;
wire b;
main main_dut(
               .a(a),
               .b(b),
               .c(c)
             );
```